# Is it possible to completely disable voice chat in-server?

Tags: team-fortress-2, voice-chat

I have some TF2 servers, but I don't want voice chat to be enabled in certain servers. For example one of the servers is an achievement server running the `achievement_idle` map and due to its nature, I don't want voice chat to be enabled (due to the fact that these servers are there so that players can idle, not talk).

Another reason for this is that 95% of the time on other servers, voice chat seems to be overrun by kids who think a good idea of fun is to shout at anyone who kills them/general abuse. As a 'mature' adult, this is something I don't *really* want happening on my servers.

I have tried the following, with nothing working to disable voice chat:

- CVar: `voice_enable 0` (does nothing as far as I can see);
- Simply requesting not to use mics (doesn't work, as the message is simply ignored);

As there is `cl_voice 0` command, is there an equivalent server command (i.e, `sv_voice 0`?)? I also have not tried `sv_allow_voice_from_file` yet, but it doesn't seem to be what I want.

I also host a TeamSpeak3 server, which I encourage players to use (as it is far superior to TF2's voice chat feature in many ways); if players *really* want to use voice chat, they can use the TS3 server to do so.

Is it possible at all to disable voice chat, server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct server cvar is `sv_voiceenable`.  If you set that to 0, it will be disabled server-wide.

You shouldn't confuse this with `voice_enable`, which is the client command to disable voice chat so that they can't hear it.

Comment: As a general rule, server cvars start with `sv_` (for server) or `mp_` (for multiplayer).  Game-specific server cvars tend to start with `tf_`